# A sensitive lent

Tags: lateral-thinking, time

The number of days from the first day of [Lent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lent) to the last day, inclusive, may be best described by:

> a) XL
>   b) Xl + VI

Comment: So what's the question here, exactly? Is it "choose between the two options"?

Comment: @Deusovi - there is some time calculation and knowledge (Wikipedia gives enough), but mostly lateral thinking clued by 'sensitive'?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question - I'm asking what the *question being asked* is here. Is it "which is better"? Right now it just looks like you're telling us some good options for describing the number of days in Lent.

Comment: The question's not asking for the number of days in Lent. To be really specific the question would give a name for the last day, but it is a commonly accepted last day.

Comment: That's still not a response to my comment. *What is the question you are asking with this puzzle?* Is it "which is better, (a) or (b)"? Is it "which of these are good descriptors [maybe one, both, or neither]"? Is it "find a hidden message in this question giving a three-digit number"? What *type of thing* are you looking for as an answer?

Comment: @Deusovi -The question is what is 'the number of days from the first day of Lent to the last day'. The answer uses a commonly accepted last day - I could give name this, but it would make the question more just a calculation. The question uses some lateral look-up, which has already been solved, though asked this question as it is often answered incorrectly, so is a bit puzzley.

Comment: Is the intended answer (b) because Lent (if reckoned as ending on Holy Saturday rather than Maundy Thursday) is in fact 46 days long rather than 40 days (although often _referred to_ as "40 days" for traditional reasons)? If so, I'm afraid I don't think this is a _puzzle_. (There was once a "trivia" tag, whose description said explicitly that things that are just trivia questions are off-topic here. That tag's gone now, though.)

Comment: Incidentally, if the lowercase L in (b) is _deliberate_ then it's rather [XKCD 169](https://www.xkcd.com/169/). But I bet it's just a typo.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan -  lowercase L in (b) is why l added the lateral thinking tag. The other puzzling part was the difference between the number of days and the  number of days from the first day to the last day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer

> b) is the hoped for answer. When examined using Notepad, I is actually a lowercase L
>  Regarding the issue of 46 days versus 40 days, 
>  46 days represents all calendar days from Ash Wednesday to Holy Saturday.

Comment: You solved the lateral-thinking part of this question, which was the main puzzle. The rest was a count from Ash Wednesday to Holy Saturday included. (Sundays are not in Lent). I'd be happy to accept if updated.

Comment: Thank you. I aimed for rot13(46 qnlf ercerfragf nyy pnyraqne qnlf sebz Nfu Jrqarfqnl gb Ubyl Fngheqnl). The lateral-thinking explanation and your total of all these days gives the one letter answer - I hope!

Comment: I may have over-stepped the edit, though you have all the essentials.

Comment: @Tom, it's fine. It takes out a lot of the unnecessary, confusing stuff I wrote. I get it now. That letter. Got it. :)